# How does rosmsg md5 calculate the md5sum?

Tags: ros, md5, ros-indigo, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I need to communicate through ros topics between two different ros versions. One of the msgs depends on trajectory_msgs which has changed between versions so it gives a md5sum error. To overcome this I tried to add the old version of trajectory_msgs to my catkin workspace and recompile. The output of rosmsg shows that after I source my workspace, the msg changes but the md5 does not, any ideas?

```
$~/indigo_ws$ rosmsg show trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint 
    float64[] positions
    float64[] velocities
    float64[] accelerations
    float64[] effort
    duration time_from_start
    
$~/indigo_ws$ rosmsg md5 trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint 
f3cd1e1c4d320c79d6985c904ae5dcd3
$~/indigo_ws$ source devel/setup.bash 
$~/indigo_ws$ rosmsg md5 trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint 
f3cd1e1c4d320c79d6985c904ae5dcd3
$~/indigo_ws$ rosmsg show trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint 
    float64[] positions
    float64[] velocities
    float64[] accelerations
    duration time_from_start
    
$~/indigo_ws$ rosmsg md5 trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint 
f3cd1e1c4d320c79d6985c904ae5dcd3
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233654/how-does-rosmsg-md5-calculate-the-md5sum?/) by [cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/11531/cardoso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name is not included in the md5sum only the content.

See the overview of how to compute the difference here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Message_serialization_and_msg_MD5_sums

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1